# Base temperature value for European Nordic Countries

Tags: temperature

I am calculating Heating Degree Days and Cooling Degree Days for European Nordic countries (Norway, Sweden, Finland, Denmark, Estonia, Latvia and Lithuania). 
On a paper (Benestad 2008) I read that the base temperature is bounded between 18°C and 22°C, but this value is too much generic for my purposes, as I have to compute exact HDD and CDD for the aforementioned countries.
Where can I retrieve Base Temperature values for Nordic countries?

UPDATE:
I found that EUROSTAT use a value of 15°C as base temperature for computing HDD and CDD. Would it be acceptable?

Comment: Are you looking for an average historical value, or for the values on a single specific date at a single specific location?

Comment: An average historical value would be better. I have to compute nation-wide HDD and CDD, therefore using a value referred only to a specific location would cause biased results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd consult their respective weather services, or perhaps if there's an EU-wide service try there.

Comment: It wouldn't have occurred to me that finding base-temperatures for HDD/CDD calculations could be an earth-science topic. And you might find that the base temps for both HDD and CDD differ between countries. Ideally, your energy consumption data should lead you to the right numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. I have found on the Eurostat website a base temperature value of 15°C. I tried to use it for my computation, and my results for Norway (as example) roughly agree with the values computed by Eurostat. Unfortunately, their time series is up to 2009, while I have to compute HDD for 2013 and 2014, therefore I can't made a better comparison. Would a value of 15°C be acceptable? In literature i have never read a so low value for base temperature for computing HDD and CDD.

Comment: Nordic housing tends to be very well insulated, so it seems plausible that heating is not required at 15 degrees, or even lower.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I am agree about the fact that for nordic countries the base temperature could be set at a lower value than 15°C, because I realize that the latter represents the average value that is generally valid for Europe; but it should be adapted while taking into account single countries, based on the characteristics of them.